# both file_get_contents and curl not working

Tags: curl, file-get-contents, php

I just used file_get_contents to retrive data in my website. But it does not returns anything.

```
file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png")
```

When i used the same in my local environment, It returns value.

I also tried curl in my website to figure out whether it returns anything.
But it shows

**Forbidden

You don't have permission to access.**

I googled and i found some hints. I enabled **allow_url_fopen** and **allow_url_include**.

But nothing working.

The curl code which i have tried

```
function curl($url){ 
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $return = curl_exec($ch); curl_close ($ch);
  return $return;
} 
$string = curl('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
echo $string;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your curl try? PS: Are you sure it's not your server fault? I just checked and it works fine for me on that specific link.

Comment: @Dainis Ablos : I have updated the question. Just look it out.

Comment: As I said, your host might be blocking calls to outside sources. [Here](http://www.dainisabols.lv/so/20878228.php) is your unchanged script on my server and it works just fine.

Comment: vinothavn - did you get to the bottom of this?  I have the same issue.  I have confirmed that allow_url_fopen is set to "On".  If anyone has any ideas where the "host might be blocking calls to outside sources" (per @Dainis Abols' comments), I'd also appreciated it - in this case the outside source actually ends up being local, but it's the rendered (json) output of a local file, not the contents of the file's source that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The **`file_get_contents()`** way...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png");
```

### The **`cURL`** way...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    $return = curl_exec($ch); curl_close ($ch);
    return $return;
}
$string = curl('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
echo $string;
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. In local environment the image is displayed but in my website it shows 
**The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors**

Comment: I checked on my server and I got through even with the `https`, so I think the OPs host doesn't allow calls to outside sources.

Comment: @DainisAbols, Maybe you're right. vinoth, What about `cURL` ?